# String Escape in Like Query not working (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, mysql, regex, codeigniter-3, trim

I have been testing my query with random strings to see if there will be results that will be displayed.

One string that I tested is **`cal`**, so the query should be simple, right?

```
SELECT c.`ID` as id, CONCAT(p.`Name`, ' > ', c.`Name`) as name, 'cal' as q 
FROM `cq_provice` p JOIN `cq_city` c ON c.`provinceID` = p.`ID` 
WHERE (CONCAT(p.`Name`, ' > ', c.`Name`) LIKE '%cal%') ORDER BY p.`Name`, c.`Name` 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

However, with my 2 prepared sql queries: one using the codeigniter way and one using the usual:

**#1**

```
$this->db->select('c.ID as id');
$this->db->select('CONCAT(p.Name, \' > \', c.Name) as name');
$this->db->select($term.' as q');
$this->db->from('cq_provice p');
$this->db->join('cq_city c', 'c.provinceID = p.ID');
$this->db->like('CONCAT(p.Name, \' > \', c.Name)', $this->db->escape($this->input->post('search')), 'both');
$this->db->order_by('p.Name', 'ASC');
$this->db->order_by('c.Name', 'ASC');
$this->db->limit($result_count, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

**#2**

```
$query = "SELECT c.`ID` as id, CONCAT(p.`Name`, ' > ', c.`Name`) as name, ".$term." as q 
          FROM `cq_provice` p JOIN  `cq_city` c ON c.`provinceID` = p.`ID` 
          WHERE (CONCAT(p.`Name`, ' > ', c.`Name`) LIKE 
          '%".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('search'))."%') 
          ORDER BY p.`Name`, c.`Name` LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$result_count;
```

And both of them is giving me the same query statement:

```
SELECT c.`ID` as id, CONCAT(p.`Name`, ' > ', c.`Name`) as name, 'cal' as q 
FROM `cq_provice` p JOIN `cq_city` c ON c.`provinceID` = p.`ID` 
WHERE (CONCAT(p.`Name`, ' > ', c.`Name`) LIKE '%'cal'%') 
ORDER BY p.`Name`, c.`Name` LIMIT 0, 50
```

My problem lies in the WHERE statement `WHERE (CONCAT(p.`Name`, ' > ', c.`Name`) LIKE '%'cal'%'` wherein the LIKE statement should be `'%cal%'` so I tried to use trim and regex but they gave me the same result:

```
SELECT c.`ID` as id, CONCAT(p.`Name`, ' > ', c.`Name`) as name, 'cal' as q 
FROM `cq_provice` p JOIN `cq_city` c ON c.`provinceID` = p.`ID` 
WHERE (CONCAT(p.`Name`, ' > ', c.`Name`) LIKE 'Êl%') 
ORDER BY p.`Name`, c.`Name` LIMIT 0, 50
```

How do I fix this? How can I prevent my query to translate my string as special characters?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: whats inside `$this->input->post('search')` ??

Comment: Hi @AbdullaNilam - The string I entered which is 'cal'

Comment: why you join both field with `\' > \'` ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam it's the format we discussed to use. But it has no connection with the problem so don't worry about it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select(array('c.ID as id','CONCAT(p.Name, " > ", c.Name) as name',$term.' as q'));
$this->db->from('cq_provice p');
$this->db->join('cq_city c', 'c.provinceID = p.ID');
$this->db->like('CONCAT(p.Name, " > ", c.Name)', $this->db->escape($this->input->post('search')));
$this->db->order_by('p.Name ASC, c.Name ASC');
$this->db->limit($result_count, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

or  with `MATCH`, `AGAINST`

```
$field = $this->db->escape($this->input->post('search'));
$this->db->select(array('c.ID as id','CONCAT(p.Name, " > ", c.Name) as name',$term.' as q'));
$this->db->from('cq_provice p');
$this->db->join('cq_city c', 'c.provinceID = p.ID');
$this->db->where('MATCH (p.Name,c.Name) AGAINST ('.$field.')', NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->order_by('p.Name ASC, c.Name ASC');
$this->db->limit($result_count, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
```